# Use R to search for a specific text pattern and return entire sentence(s) where pattern appears

Tags: r, text-mining

So I scanned in a physical document, changed it to a tiff image and used the package Tesseract to import it into R. However, I need R to look for specific keywords, find it in the text file and return the entire line that the keyword is in.

For example, if I had the text file:

> This is also straightforward. Look at the years of experience required and see if that matches the years of experience that the candidate has. It is important to note that if the candidate matches or exceeds the years of experience required, you would rate both of those scenarios a “5”.

And I tell R to search for the keyword "straightforward", how do I get it to return "This is also straightforward...see if that matches the"?

Comment: There are no line-breaks in your text file, but you might consider `readLines` to read in the file line-by-line first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `quanteda` package that breaks the text into sentences, and then uses `grep()` to return the sentence containing the word "straightforward".

```
aText <- "This is also straightforward. Look at the years of experience required and see if that matches the years of experience that the candidate has. It is important to note that if the candidate matches or exceeds the years of experience required, you would rate both of those scenarios a “5”."
library(quanteda)
aCorpus <- corpus(aText)
theSentences <- tokens(aCorpus,what="sentence")
grep("straightforward",theSentences,value=TRUE)
```

and the output:

```
> grep("straightforward",theSentences,value=TRUE)
                          text1 
"This is also straightforward."
```

To search for multiple keywords, add them in the `grep()` function via the or operator | .

```
grep("straightforward|exceeds",theSentences,value=TRUE)
```

...and the output:

```
> grep("straightforward|exceeds",theSentences,value=TRUE)

text1 

"This is also straightforward." 

<NA> 
"It is important to note that if the candidate matches or exceeds the years of experience required, you would rate both of those scenarios a \"5\"."
```

> 

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there a way to search for multiple keywords at a time and return multiple lines with those keywords or do I have to write a grep function for each keyword?

Comment: You can add keywords in the list to be searched via the or operator, | . I'll update the post with another example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R option:

```
text <- "This is also straightforward. Look at the years of experience required and see if that matches the years of experience that the candidate has. It is important to note that if the candidate matches or exceeds the years of experience required, you would rate both of those scenarios a “5”."
lst <- unlist(strsplit(text, "(?<=[a-z]\\.\\s)", perl=TRUE))
lst[grepl("\\bstraightforward\\b", lst)]
```

I am splitting your text on the pattern `(?<=[a-z]\\.\\s)`, which says to lookbehind for a lowercase letter, following by a full stop and a space.  This should work well most of the time.  There is the issue of abbreviations, but most of the time they would be in the form of capital letter followed by dot, and also most of the time they would not be ending sentences.

### Demo